# anaconda python distribution completely free even for commercial use?

Tags: python, licensing, enterprise, anaconda

https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/

I see there are prices for add-ons like Numbapro. But its say it completely free at the top of the home page. I cannot find licensing information.

am i understanding this correctly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Comment: if this is offtopic, where in stack exchange can this question be posted, taking into account is a *very relevant* question for developers in our daily work

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Anaconda itself was completely free, even for commercial use, until April 2020.
Since then, you need to buy a commercial license if you make commercial use of their repositories at https://repo.anaconda.com or the `anaconda` channel on https://anaconda.org. The term *commercial* focuses on larger companies requiring more bandwith than a single OSS developer or scientist.

Read more about the details in the new [Terms of Service](https://www.anaconda.com/terms-of-service) or the [Anaconda Commercial Edition FAQ](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/anaconda-commercial-edition-faq).

Comment: I had to ask because i could not believe it.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is no longer true in 2020 it seems. https://www.anaconda.com/blog/anaconda-commercial-edition-faq

Comment: Does anyone have a link to the previous TOS, before the April 2020 change? Couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: @CorneliusRoemer: You could download one of the old installers, e.g. of Anaconda 2019.07. They contain the EULA document which should describe the old usage terms.

Comment: Currently, the cut-off point for commercial usage is >200 employees. It's not about bandwidth, the bandwidth just seems like an excuse to start charging (2PB/year costs only $100k at AWS), mirroring is prohibited, too, despite the whole repo only having around 60GB.

Comment: I am using Anaconda3 2022.10 , where can I find its licence id/number?

Comment: If you work at a large company, but you are the only one using Anaconda (ie. not a company-wide used tool) is that still considered commercial?

Comment: @Jaol, yes it's considered commercial, the licensing terms of anaconda target companies with more than 200 employees.

Answer (score 9):

The full EULA can be found [here](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/eula.html), and is also included in the installer (you must agree to it before installing Anaconda).

The gist of it is that you can use Anaconda however you want (including for commercial use). You only need to attribute it with something like "Powered by Anaconda".

Note that the code itself for the packages in Anaconda may have other licenses, which may be more or less restrictive. For instance, most of the packages are BSD or similarly licensed, which is less restrictive. A few are GPL or LGPL, which are more restrictive.  There is a list of the licenses of the Anaconda packages [here](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/licenses.html).